# How to take elements by Selenium which created by JS script

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-testing

I trying automating testing with Selenium (python bindings), specifically want to log in on tokmonet.zendesk.com.
I create a script which takes email field, password field and sign in button by id.
But when I ran script it fails with

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"user_email"}
```

Inspecting page with Firebug I see these elements. But when trying to get them with Firefinder it couldn't.
So, I perform

```
html_source = driver.page_source  
print(html_source)
```

and get the only

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>
```

When I check page source it contains only js scripts and no mark up.

Please advice how I could handle this elements?

Comment: Try to wait until elements load in the page and then perform operations on them. Here's a small example - `driver.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id('user_email')))`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it didn't help. TimeoutException was thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch to the `IFRAME`, then `send_keys()` to the element which you can find by ID. Don't forget to switch back to the default content if you need to access elements outside the `IFRAME`.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
driver.find_element_by_id("user_email").send_keys("username")
driver.find_element_by_id("user_password").send_keys("password")
// do whatever else
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that elements that you are trying to log in are in an iframe in `tokmonet.zendesk.com` and so you are not able to get the elements. To handle such situation try to switch to the iframe first and then get the elements. Here's how to do it in Java -

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20))
          .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("user_email"))).sendKeys("username");
//Similarly you can get other elements too
```

You similarly implement it in other languages. Hope this helps.

Comment: There's no need for that complicated of an XPath or even to use an XPath when you have an ID available.

Comment: Idea is to show how it can be implemented. It's not a matter of using xpath or id or class. Locators can be modified however the user wants. Point is user had to switch to the iframe to perform operations.

Comment: Hopefully when we submit an answer, it's not just "an answer"... it's an answer that not only answers the question but is the best answer possible because these answers aren't just for the OP they are for all future readers. The best answer follows best practices, is well organized and well thought out. The OP (and others) should be able to take this answer and not only solve their problem but learn something about good programming practices.

Comment: There are far too many people on SO using complicated XPaths for simple cases. There is no reason to use an XPath in this case when you have an ID. XPaths are significantly slower and more complicated that needed for this simple task. XPaths have their place but this isn't one of them.

Comment: I understand. Updated the answer with the proper details. Thanks for guiding :)